# How do I bind stored procedure single result set with single class object result?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6, sqlparameter

I have a stored procedure which returns following result set:

```
Id : int
Name : string
Image : string
Address : string
```

Code:

```
public class SPResultSet
{
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public string Image { get; set; }
       //other additional properties
} 

var data = ctx.Database
              .SqlQuery<SPResultSet>("[dbo].[GET_Data] params", sqlParameters)
              .FirstOrDefault();
```

Error :

> System.ArgumentException: 'No mapping exists from object type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] to a known managed provider native type.'

How do I bind the stored procedure's single result set with single class object result?

**Note:** the stored procedure returns only 1 row of data.

Comment: Can you please show what parameters are you passing?

Comment: error is sqlParameters, seems type is wrong , try converting sqlParameters to array

Comment: @Nonik Yes, sqlParameters.ToArray() solved the issue. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: By the way, unless you always pass the parameters in the correct order, you should always use the following syntax `[dbo].[GET_Data] @param1 = @param1, @param2 = @param2...`. And ideally you want to change the command type so that instead of an ad-hoc batch, it calls the procedure directly, so you need `CommandType.StoredProcedure` and then the query string is just `[dbo].[GET_Data]`. But I'm not sure if you can do that with EF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not pass the parameters as list, you should pass the each parameter to the stored procedure.

Or it could be passed as `sqlParameters.ToArray()` in your case.

**Note**: It would be great if you provide the complete code with parameters you are passing and the stored procedure.

Comment: You are right. sqlParameters.ToArray() solved the issue. Thank you so much for helping me and for quick answer. Appreciated :)